# Chatroom app only updates messages when send button is pressed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, chatroom

I've only just started using pyQt6 as of today, as tkinter was giving me some issues, however now that I have the base of the app working, I'm faced with an issue, my chat (self.output) will only update with new messages anytime that the send button is pressed, this of course is not how I would like it to be working, I'd rather it update once a message has been sent from the server, is there any solution to this problem?

Here is the code

```
from ast import Delete
import socket
import threading
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
import rsa
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9090

shost = '127.0.0.1'
sport = 9090


def loadKeys():
    with open('keys/publicKey.pem', 'rb') as p:
        publicKey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(p.read())
    with open('keys/privateKey.pem', 'rb') as p:
        privateKey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(p.read())
    return privateKey, publicKey

def encrypt(message, key):
    return rsa.encrypt(message.encode('utf-8'), key)

def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    try:
        return rsa.decrypt(ciphertext, key).decode('utf-8')
    except:
        return False
def sign(message, key):
    return rsa.sign(message.encode('utf-8'), key, 'SHA-1')

def verify(message, signature, key):
    try:
        return rsa.verify(message.encode('utf-8'), signature, key,) == 'SHA-1'
    except:
        return False

privateKey, publicKey = loadKeys()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((shost,sport))

gui_done = False

running = True



class Chatroom(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Harmonic")
        self.resize(1920,1080)

        self.nickname = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Nickname', 'Enter your nickname:')
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        QApplication.processEvents()

        self.inputField = QLineEdit()
        button = QPushButton('&Send')
        button.clicked.connect(self.write)
        self.output = QTextEdit()

        layout.addWidget(self.inputField)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        layout.addWidget(self.output)
        self.Gui_done = True
        self.restoremessages()
        receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
        receive_thread.start()

    def restoremessages(self):
        with open('chathistory.txt', 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                self.output.append('{0}'.format(line))
    def write(self):
        message = (f"{self.nickname}: {self.inputField.text()}\n")
        emessage = encrypt(message, publicKey)
        sock.send(emessage)
        self.inputField.clear()
    def stop(self):
        running = False
        sock.close
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def receive(self):
        while running:
            try:
                message = sock.recv(10000)
                dm = decrypt(message,privateKey)
                if message == "NICK":
                    sock.send(self.nickname.encode())
                else:
                    self.output.append('{0}'.format(dm))
                    QApplication.processEvents
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                print("Connection aborted")
                sock.close()
                break
            except:
                print("Error")
                sock.close()
                break
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        close = QMessageBox.question(self, "QUIT", "Are you sure you want to stop the process?", QMessageBox.StandardButton.Yes | QMessageBox.StandardButton.No)
        if close == QMessageBox.StandardButton.Yes:
            event.accept()
            self.stop()
        else:
            event.ignore()


window = Chatroom()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

There are certain parts of the code that are redundent that I am aware of, same the error with `sys.exit(app.exec_())` for some reason the program would not exit without me throwing an error to do so, so this will have to do for now.

Comment: You cannot directly interact with the UI from external threads, as widgets are not thread safe. Use a QThread, override its `run()` method with the contents of `receive` and implement a custom signal connected to the function that will actually add the text when a message is received.

Comment: I managed to get this code working by moving the QApplication.processEvents, above the append function.

Comment: still it is encouraged to use QThread for updating the UI Elements or using for purpose of multithreading in QT Application